# how to fix "Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'"?

Tags: android-studio

i'm building an app based on MicroREPL (available on [github](https://github.com/Ma7moud3ly/micro-repl)) but i'm having problems getting started because i can't build the app. i'm getting these errors.

```
A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=18, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.
```

```
A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=18, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not create task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'javaCompiler'.
No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=18, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} for WINDOWS on x86_64.
No locally installed toolchains match and toolchain download repositories have not been configured.
    at 
...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

i'm using gradle 8.2 and the gradle plugin 8.1.2 on android studio giraffe build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636.
runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
vm: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

i tried updating gradle, android studio, even java, installed a kotlin compiler both externally and through android studio, and nothing worked. i can't build the application.
how to proceed?